# Redirect using virtual host domain name beginning with https

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, virtualhost

I am trying to redirect ME.com or www.ME dot com to https://NOTME dot com.
The code below works but when i type https://ME dot com it doesn't go to https://NOTME dot com. i get an error that page is unsecure.
code below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@ME dot com
ServerName ME dot com
    ServerAlias www dot ME dot com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www dot ME dot com
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://NOTME dot com/$1 [L,R=301]
Redirect permanent / https://NOTME dot com/
DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx/xxx/
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/xxxx/xxxxx/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
```

Also note that i set ME.com had an https certificate that i removed which was set at virtual host port 443. Can i also still return the certificate to it?
Also both ME.com and NOTME.com are on the same server IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solved this problem:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin x@ME.com
ServerName ME.com
ServerAlias www.ME.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ME.COM/$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://NOTME.COM/$1 [L,R=301]
Redirect permanent / https://NOTME.COM/

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /xxxxxxxxxxxx.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /xxxxxxxxxxxx.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.crt
```

Actually the solution was a permanent redirect to NOTME dot com